# How do I use selenium in Python to open up a Chromium browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to use selenium to open up a Chromium browser but whenever I run the python file in terminal, Chromium pops up but in the terminal, I can see that it automatically exits right after.

I'm using macOS Sonoma.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()

requests.get("http://www.google.com")

def web_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = '/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium'
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1200")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    return driver

driver = web_driver()

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The path to chromedriver is: Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

If your code is opening a Chrome browser, then it is functioning as expected. Selenium will close once it finishes, unless you add the Option of "detach" to keep it running. Simply add this line to your web_driver() function:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Comment: It didn't work :/ I'm wondering if it might be because of the Chrome/Chromium versions (122) vs. the chromedriver version?

Comment: Why are you specifying the binary location? Are you on an old version of Selenium? If not, try deleting that option